# Вопросы по qtdesigner

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

1) Какие плюсы и минусы compile-time и run-time обработки .ui файлов?

2) Надо ли распространять .ui файлы в сорсах проекта или только генерируемые uic заголовочные файлы?

Comment: что за «run-time обработки .ui файлов»? по поводу второго — да, `*.ui` почти всегда распространяются вместе с исходниками.

Comment: @Fat-Zer под compile-time имеется в виду `.ui -> .h -> компилируем`, под run-time -- используем QUILoader, чтобы во время выполнения загрузить ui

Comment: мм... как-то я пропустил существование `QUILoader`=))...

Answer (score 0):

При работе с файлами дизайнера, прикрепленными к непосредственно к проекту и собираемыми метаобъектным компилятором, можно нарваться на необходимость [собирать проект с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962852/233158) из-за некорректного выхлопа утилиты QMake. Кроме того, если необходимо спроектировать современно выглядящий пользовательский интерфейс, не обойтись без css стилей (градиенты, картинки, цвета), это дело легче разрабатывать инкрементально, используя функцию предпросмотра Qt Designer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюсы работы с файлами дизайнера из-под Qt Creator, а не Qt Designer сомнительны: на мой взгляд, Qt Creator реализует исключительно предпросмотр форм дизайнера и не более того. Часто, код, генерируемый Qt Designer обрабатывают и добавляют в саму программу руками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюсом такого подхода является свобода выбора относительно наследования или использования экземпляра QDialog, в который будет осуществлен вывод самих виджетов. Так же, можно использовать систему сборки, отличную от QMake.

**Вывод:**
В проекте на C++ лучше держать исходные коды программы на C++, исключение - ресурсы. Файлы ui, на мой взгляд, рационально держать от основной программы отдельно, например, в директории, параллельной папке проекта, или отдельном git репозитории.