# QtCreator C++. Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, qtcreator

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "graphicsscene.h"

namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QGraphicsView *graph;
    QWidget *buttonsWidget;
    QWidget *statusWidget;
    CustomScene *scene;


public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;



};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    graph = ui->graphicsView; // Initialize pointer for graphics view
    scene = new CustomScene(); // Тут ошибка
    scene->setSceneRect(ui->graphicsView->rect()); // Set size and positon for scene
    scene->addLine(0,0,200,200); // Test
    graph->setScene(scene); // Set scene on graphics view

    statusWidget = ui->StatusWidget; // Initialize pointer for own widget "Status Widget"

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete scene;
    delete ui;
}

//graphicsscene.h

#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>


class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~CustomScene();

signals:
    // Сигнал для передачи координат положения курсора мыши
    void signalTargetCoordinate(QPointF point);

public slots:

private:
    // Функция, в которой производится отслеживание положения мыши
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H

//graphicsscene.cpp
#include "graphicsscene.h"

CustomScene::CustomScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene()
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
}

CustomScene::~CustomScene()
{

}

void CustomScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    emit signalTargetCoordinate(event->scenePos());
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний
>   символ "public: __thiscall CustomScene::CustomScene(class QObject *)"
>   (??0CustomScene@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z) в функции "public: __thiscall
>   MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)"
>   (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)`

и если два раза нажать по ней то пишет `Файл не найден в:mainwindow.obj`.

Если я бы обьявил в `mainwindow.h` мой `CustomScene` и определил в `mainwindow.cpp` , то ошибки не было, но как сделать так, чтобы ну вот в в других файлах был CustomScene?

Comment: При создании новых наследников QObject нужно перезапустить метаобъектную компиляцию. Обычно я тупо удаляю директории, которые запиливает QMake, и это помогает.

Comment: Очистите и пересоберите проект

Comment: Обычно, рядом с директорией текущего проекта создаются папки с названием вида build-qtcreator-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Debug. Попробуй удалить такую. Или через меню сборки в самом Qt Creator

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/34tgWaV523P1E8TF6

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр да, я просто удалил папку эту и все заработало. Спасибо большое))

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр Можно вас спросить ? Вот компилятор написал, что не найден файл в обьектном файле, это значит что он там не было определения или обьявления ? Или вообще ни того, ни другого ? Или линковщик просто не включил в `obj`-файл мой `graphicsscene.h` ? Ну , в общем, почему такая ошибка, вы не знаете?

Comment: Ошибка в IDE при клике вызвана тем, что писали её люди, которым IDE не нужна и они забили болт. Что же касается природы ошибки сборки непосредственно - не забывайте, что механизм сигналов/слотов это синтаксический сахар и компилироваться не может. Его разворачивает в код C++ утилита QMake, которая дописывает за вас файлы. Гляньте в папку - там лежат посторонние файлы moc_predefs.h, moc_mainwindow.cpp и тд. Ради экономии времени она стремиться генерировать как можно только меньше кода и не всегда получается свести воедино - приходится давать делать ей по новой.

Comment: @Kaznachei, оформил эту переписку в ответ на вопрос. Если не жалко - отметьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании новых наследников QObject нужно перезапустить метаобъектную компиляцию. Обычно, рядом с директорией текущего проекта создаются папки с названием вида build-qtcreator-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Debug. Попробуй удалить такую. Или через меню сборки в самом Qt Creator

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы, это так же можно сделать и из самого Qt Creator, но я всегда именно удаляю папку с метаобъектным кодом, сгенерированным утилитой QMake.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас отсутствует определение конструктора `CustomScene(QObject *)`, точнее объявление есть и оно "видно" в `MainWindow`, а определения (тела то есть) нет. Либо вы не включили в проект файл `.cpp` где определен нужный конструктор, либо в имеющихся конструкторах другой набор аргументов.

Comment: Вот вроде бы `CustomScene::CustomScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene()
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
}
` определение. В файле `graphicsscene.cpp`

Comment: Я убрал из аргументов  `QObject *` для конструктора `CustomScene`. Не помогает